# How to add navigation links in c# windows application

Tags: c#

I want to create a form with 2 panels in which the left panel contains links. When a link is clicked, the corresponding form should open up in the right area and should refresh when another link is clicked and should show that form. I want to do this in c# windows application. How do I do it?

Comment: What problem did you have when you tried this?

Comment: the right panel was not getting refreshed when the second link is clicked , the right panel content is constant.

Comment: Show a small example of the problem

Answer (score 1):

As @AVD suggests for link you should use `LinkLabel` but in order to open forms in 'right' or anyother specified panel, you have to set the Parent handle of Forms to the handle of containing Panel.

So lets say you have two panels, `splitContainer1.LeftPanel` and `splitContainer1.RightPanel`. In left Panel you have `LinkLabel` with `LinkClicked` event. Now in order to open a Form in `splitContainer1.RightPanel` when `LinkLabel` is clicked, instantiate an object of Form, call the Win API method `SetParent()` to set the parent handle and then call the `Form.Show()` method to open it in `splitContainer1.RightPanel`

```
//Declare a WinAPI method
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

//Inside LinkClicked event
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
      Form1 f = new Form1();
      SetParent(f.Handle, splitContainer1.Panel2.Handle);
      f.Show();
}
```

**Edit: A workaround to close any existing form in panel before opening a new**
Not the best but easiest way to close existing form:

```
Form currentForm = null;
private void CloseCurrentForm()
{
    if(currentForm != null)
       currentForm.Close();
}
```

and in every `LinkClicked` event call this method before opening a new `Form` like this, don't forget to set the `currentForm`:

```
private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
      CloseCurrentForm();
      Form2 f = new Form2();
      SetParent(f.Handle, splitContainer1.Panel2.Handle);
      currentForm = f; 
      f.Show();
}
```

Comment: actually if i do this then a new window is overlapping the former in the right panel,but i want that the old form should hide and new one should only display, there should be no overlap of forms one above the another.

Comment: how to open a popup form from a form which is in the right panel in the panel in the split container and not outside it.

Comment: it's simple just make the popup window a child of panel or the form inside panel

Comment: how to do it?what's the code.it is giving build errors.like- name 'SetParent' does not exist in the current context and name 'splitContainer1' does not exist in the current context. Actually i kept a button in the form in right panel and when it is clicked, a popup window opens.

Comment: splitContainer is just a control i was using to split form in two and in order to use SetParent you have to declare it it's a WinAPI method, please look at the DllImport part of my answer

Answer (score 1):

For your problems, you can use Panel controls. and User Controls.   First create UserControl, Then you can add it to the panel container.   UserControls help to re usability, and will be easier to re use it.

Steps to do

1. Create a user control and design it accoriding to your need
2. Put a panel Control
3. Load the Usercontrol object in Panel and display it

For Eg .

U put one Link Label or Image or Button in your Left Side of Form, and in right side the content Panel .

when u clicked LinkLabel do the following

```
Protected void LinkLabel_Click()
{
UserControl1 UserObj =new UserControl1();   // UserControl which u want to display 

panel1.controls.Clear(); 
Panel1.Controls.Add(userobj);     //Adding the control to Panel Container. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LinkLabel` control and create `MDI` to open/show child `forms`.

Comment: the right panel was not getting refreshed when the second link is clicked , the right panel content is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the **Custom Properties** used in c# to open new forms, try it here. Use the Link button.

Comment: the right panel was not getting refreshed when the second link is clicked , the right panel content is constant.

Comment: You have already defined all the controls or not. If not then you can easily redraw all the controls on click of the link button.                                                                http://en.csharp-online.net/Panel

Answer (score 0):

I think you searching for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.aspx . LinkLabel control. Handle its LinkClicked event and do what you want.

Comment: the right panel was not getting refreshed when the second link is clicked , the right panel content is constant.